# Should 'is' or 'are' be used before a list of possible types of one thing?

Tags: word-choice

I'm considering editing a Stack Overflow question titled:

> What is functional, declarative and imperative programming?

It seems like "are" should be used instead of "is" since it comes before a list of things, and if you weren't familiar with the topic it might sound like it was asking about one type of programming that was all three of those at the same time. But does it make a difference when the list of things is a list of adjectives describing a single thing? I mean, does the "is" or "are" apply to the "functional, declarative and imperative" or to "programming"?

I know that the sentence actually means

> functional programming, declarative programming, and imperative programming

and if I write it like that it seems clear that "are" should be used, but for some reason when I look at the original sentence, both "is" and "are" look wrong.

I'm not sure of the terminology I should use to refer to a sentence with this structure, so I'd also appreciate it if someone could tell me if there is a name for this type of "distributive" list.

Comment: [The question in case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602444/what-is-functional-declarative-and-imperative-programming) - it doesn't hurt to link to it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't sure if I should or not.

Comment: If, as seems likely here, these are three distinct areas are being specified, 'are' is required. 'What is A, what is B, and what is C?' reduces to 'What are A, B and C?' However, 'Health and safety is paramount' treats [H+S] as a single composite topic. _Notional_ vs 'as grammar would seem to dictate' agreement has often been covered here before.

Comment: This type of "distributive" list *(functional, declarative and imperative programming)* is simply a ***noun phrase*** (compound noun, if you like). Sometimes the "plurality" is obvious even without further context, so *big and small sheep* pretty much *has* to refer to more than one sheep. But [*terrified and exhausted deer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22terrified+and+exhausted+deer%22) either refers to a *single* animal or several treated collectively (not one or more terrified deer, *plus* one or more other deer who are exhausted but not terrified). It's all just common sense.

Comment: Right. If one single type of programming needs to be functional, declarative and imperative, you use the single: is. If these are three competing approaches to programming, you use the plural: are.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It seems obvious after your comments. I guess it should have seemed obvious _before_ your comments, but I was too busy overthinking it. In the meantime, my original reason for asking this has evaporated, but hopefully this will help me to avoid confusing myself with something similar in the future.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - very clear.  Please post as an answer.

Comment: @aparente001 I've stated that this has been covered on ELU before. Please don't encourage duplicate threads.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I see.  When I read your comment the first time, I missed the last five words.  Maybe it would be better not to explain in a comment, then, and provide a link to an answered equivalent question.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> This type of "distributive" list *(functional, declarative and imperative programming)* is simply a ***noun phrase*** (compound noun, if you like). Sometimes the "plurality" is obvious even without further context, so *big and small sheep* pretty much *has* to refer to more than one sheep. But [*terrified and exhausted deer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22terrified+and+exhausted+deer%22) either refers to a *single* animal or several treated collectively (not one or more terrified deer, *plus* one or more other deer who are exhausted but not terrified). It's all just common sense.